# Gauss's Lemma for UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I have to prove the following

> Let R be a unique factorization domain. Then the product of primitive
> polynomials in R[x] is primitive.

The author says the proof is the same of that for the case R = ℤ, just replace ℤ by R and prime by irreducible. The proof goes like this

> Assume by contradiction that f(x)g(x) is not primitive. Then there
> exists a **prime number p** dividing all the coefficients of f(x)g(x).
> ...

My question is why have I to replace the notions of prime and irreducible element if in a unique factorization domain they coincide? Which is pretty much the same situation we have in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: They coincide, but I think we like to think about them as irreducibles more, because factorization is like decomposing an element until they cannot be further decomposed (i.e. irreducible).

Comment: So technically you do not need to replace prime by irreducible.

Comment: They do  not exactly coincide: irreducible elements are generators of principal prime ideals. A U.F.D. which is not a P.I.D. has non-principal prime ideals (e.g. polynomials in several indeterminates over a field).

Comment: I know that they do not exactly coincide, but I want to understand whether the difference is significant to prove the proposition or not. It seems to me that also in the proof for the case $ R = $\mathbb{Z}$ I could have used irreducible instead of prime.

Comment: What they want you to do is to replace the notion of “prime number” (i.e., prime element in $\mathbb{Z}$) with the notion of “irreducible/prime element in $R$”. In a UFD, the two notions are the same, but here the replacement is “number” to “element”. They are less than clear, but it’s okay.